# UTF-8 changes ranomly when i refresh my page

Tags: php, html, encoding

My page has worked perfectly until yesterday without change anything started to not recognize accents and the letter ñ. That happens just with the data from the database (Mysql) and if i refresh the page sometimes works fine and sometimes changes just a few words, not all, and sometimes all words so it's difficult to know why this is happening. I have the meta charset in my html with utf8, the headers HTTP looks fine, i have utf8mb4_spanish_ci in the database and in the tables and i also proved to save my files in UTF-8 with BOM and without it and still doing the same. I also change the charset in all connections with set_charset("utf8") but the problem persists. I don't know what more to do.

Thank you

Comment: At some point, the charset is broken, and without any context or code, its hard for us to say for sure. Make sure you set headers to UTF8, all tables, DB connections and such to UTF8. Just takes one to  break it.

Comment: Also note that any data already stored with a broken charset can't be magically fixed, that data needs to be updated - so you should check the data in your DB as well